# Is required SecurityContextHolder in JWT Authentication App?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jjwt

I'm developing application in Spring Boot and I need jwt authentication there. I decide to use that github project, but when I'm looking at code I don't understand sense of SecurityContextHolder.

Here are 2 classes which are using it:

[AuthenticationRestController.java](https://github.com/szerhusenBC/jwt-spring-security-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/org/zerhusen/security/controller/AuthenticationRestController.java)

[JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter.java](https://github.com/szerhusenBC/jwt-spring-security-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/org/zerhusen/security/JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter.java)

Can you tell me what is purpose of SecurityContextHolder? I want stateless authentication without session. So I just need generate jwt and next check it before requests.

This git project also has disable session:

```
...
httpSeccurity.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
...
```

I've tried delete code with SecurityContextHolder and applicatin still works fine.

Thanks for answers.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the official spring security jwt project, `spring-security-jwt`

Comment: isn't it work only with oauth2?

Comment: Oops, yea you are correct it isn't it's own project, oops. it is part of the `spring-security-oauth2` project. Is there any reason you don't want to use oauth2? It is highly customizable

Comment: I know but I just need jwt token

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quote from [Learning Spring 5.0](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/learning-spring-50):

> One major aspect of security is storing the information of the principal currently used by the application. It is held by the security context of the application. *SecurityContextHolder* is the most important object of the framework as it stores the details about security context in *ThreadLocal*. It means the security context will be available to the methods that are executed in the same thread. However, in a few circumstances, all the threads in the application may need to use other strategies for using the security context. The framework provides two ways to change the default nature of using *ThreadLocal*. The developers can either set the system property or they can invoke the static method on *SecurityContextHolder*.

The reason your application still works after deleting code with [SecurityContextHolder](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/current-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContextHolder.html) is that by using the [SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/current-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/security/config/http/SessionCreationPolicy.html#STATELESS) creation policy you request Spring Security to not create an HTTP session and not store logged in user’s [SecurityContext](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/current-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContext.html) in the session.

**When to use *SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS***

- to stop creating sessions during the entire lifespan of the application
- to stop using sessions during the entire lifespan of the application

Comment: So in my case I can keep deleted because is useless, right?

Comment: Yes, if the intention is to stop creating/using sessions.